# How can I show that $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n i^2$ is $O (n^3)$

Tags: asymptotics

I am preparing for an exam, and one of the problems on the study guide is:

> Show that $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n i^2$ is $O (n^3)$

If we declare n as some arbitrary number 5, then our summation would read $1^2$ + $2^2$ + $3^2$ + $4^2$ + $5^2$

Everything I have researched would suggest to me that this should be $O (n^2)$.  How do we come up with $O (n^3)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Note that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^2 \le n^2 + n^2 + \cdots + n^2.$$

Comment: Makes sense, but I am still not sure how that shows it is O($n^3$)

Comment: What does that sum up to?

Comment: Oh, I think maybe I understand.  The RHS would be ≤ n•$n^2$, which is $n^3$ ?

Comment: Yup quite right!

Comment: Gotcha!  But how were you able to set the RHS ≤ $n^2$ + $n^2$ + ... + $n^2$ to begin with?

Comment: Each of the individual terms is less than $n^2$. $1^2 \le n^2$, $2^2 \le n^2$, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the kind help :)

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 4):

It is not difficult to show that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2} = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \frac{n^{3}}{3} + \frac{n^{2}}{2} + \frac{n}{6} 
\end{align}
Since the highest power on $n$ is 3 then it can be stated that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2} \sim \mathcal{O}(n^{3})
\end{align}